# ¿Cómo ordenar un JSON alfabéticamente desde una key? Con Python

Tags: python, json

Estoy aprendiendo a usar JSON, pero algo que no he logrado resolver es, cómo, a partir de una key, ordenar todo el JSON, alfabéticamente, por ejemplo, este JSON:

```
{
    "Juegos": [
        {
        "Titulo": "C",
    },
    {
        "Titulo": "A",
    },
    {
        "Titulo": "B",
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer, para que quede así?:

```
{
    "Juegos": [
        {
            "Titulo": "A",
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "B",
        },
        {
            "Titulo": "C",
        }
```

Comment: En python no existen los json. Eso es un JSON generado por el módulo json o es un diccionario?

Comment: Hola @Christian, es un JSON generado por el módulo JSON, probé ordenarlo con sorted y lambda, pero no logré mas que un error

Comment: claramente, por que la función sorted no ordena json, deberás de convertirlo a un diccionario para poder ordenarlo

Comment: @Christian creo haberlo hecho, with open("Juegos.json") as f:
    juegos = json.load(f) una vez hecho esto, probé usando sorted con juegos, también probé for x in juegos["Juegos"]: print(sorted(x, key=lambda k: k["Titulo"])

Comment: Luego de haberlo cargado solo debes hacer `sorted(juegos ["Juegos"], key=lambda x: x["Titulo"])`

Comment: @Christian me funcionó, gracias, probé cosas parecidas y no me funcionó, estoy sorprendido, una pregunta, después de especificar lambda como key, ¿el carácter debe ser x o puede ser cualquiera? ¿Qué significarían esos caracteres?

Comment: la sintaxis de una lambda es `lambda <parametros>: <operación>`

Comment: ¿Qué utilidad presta lo que pides? El JSON terminará en un diccionario, una estructura de datos para acceso aleatorio ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto tienes que transformar el json generado a un diccionario, para esto se utiliza el método `loads`.

```py
with open("archivo.json") as f:
    data = json.loads(f)

ordenado = sorted(data["Juegos"], key=lambda x: x["Titulo"])
```

Con eso ya estaría ordenado